# String Array and ConvertTo-HTML

Tags: .net, powershell

I cant for the life of me get the contents of a string array (well its not strictly typed but all the items in the array are strings) to become a table, i am trying to use ConvertTo-HTML.

For example:

```
$arr = @("One", "Two")
$arr | ConvertTo-HTML
```

I have tried -As List, using fragments, even using InputObject, is it even possible ?

Edit: i simply want to know if there is anyway to use an array as the input for the ConvertTo-HTML cmdlet, all it does is make a table with the length property of the strings.

Comment: @DavidStratton ConvertTo-HTML is a cmdlet that automatically generates html for you, i dont want to have to generate it manually.

Comment: @DavidStratton if you have ever used the ConvertTo-HTML cmdlet you will know what im talking about, also it does say to become a table.

Comment: OK.  Withdrawing my comments.  My bad.  And now that I'm aware of it and googled it, COOL!  Something new to learn!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another way using the `Select-Object` cmdlet and calculated properties:

```
'one','two','three' | Select-Object @{Name='String';Expression={$_}},@{Name='Length';Expression={$_.Length}}
```

Comment: THANKS!! This is actually what i was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

`ConvertTo-HTML` will take a collection of .NET object and output the HTML for a nice table diplaying the objects' public properties.

`System.String` only has 1 public property: Length.  So you will get a table with 1 column: Length.  This is by design and consistent with normal behavior.

But it sounds like you don't want a table of the public properties of your collection objects.  You want a table with the `Length` property, and a column with the `ToString()` value.

To achieve this, we can simply create a custom object whose properties match this goal:

```
'one','two','three' |%{ New-Object PsObject -Prop @{Length = $_.Length; String = $_} } | ConvertTo-HTML
```

Comment: Experience ;)  `New-Object PsObject -Prop @{ ... }` comes in handy quite often.